# Simplify polynomials with simple subfactors

Tags: simplifying-expressions, factorization

I am trying to simplify expressions such as

```mma
poly = 1 + (-2 + 4 a^2) x^2 + x^4
```

to the form

```
polySimple = (1-x^2)^2 + 4 a^2 x^2
```

Applying Simplify to `poly` does not give `polySimple`, even when I define

```
f[e_] := StringLength[ToString[InputForm[e]]]
```

and then try

```
Simplify[poly, ComplexityFunction -> f]
```

Note that `f[poly]=26`, while `f[polySimple]=23`, so I would have thought the above would have worked.  Any ideas on how to get `polySimple`?

Comment: For this simple example you can use `Collect[poly,a,Simplify]`. The behaviour of `Simplify` is quite mysterious to me. For example, the intermediate result `1 - 2 x^2 + 4 a^2 x^2 + x^4` has complexity `27`, so we append `f[1-2 x^2+4 a^2 x^2+x^4]=25` by hand, but the result is still not `polySimple`. I guess that there are more involved things like attributes and inner definitions influcing the intermediate steps.

Comment: Thanks!  That does work for the simple example.  I note that my original problem was to simplify a rational fraction where the polynomials in the numerator and denominator had the structure of poly (but were different ones).  Your solution works separately for the numerator and denominator, but not when naively applied to the rational polynomial.  (The "Collect" variable was the same in both cases.)  So it's still a bit mysterious....

Comment: Try setting `f[e_]:=(Sow[e];StringLength[ToString[InputForm[e]]])` and then `DeleteDuplicates[ClearSystemCache[];Reap[Simplify[1+(-2+4*a^2)*x^2+x^4,ComplexityFunction->f]][[2,1]]]`. If I interpret the result correctly, the expression that you are suggesting is never tried. It makes sense that not all expressions are tried. You could perhaps have it generate more expressions using `TransformationFunctions -> ...`. Maybe someone more knowledgeable will tell us.

Comment: You could add @yurie 's Collect to the transformation functions, as in `f[e_]:=StringLength[ToString[InputForm[e]]];
t[e_]:=Collect[e,a,Simplify];
Simplify[poly,ComplexityFunction->f,TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,t}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
poly = 1 + (-2 + 4 a^2) x^2 + x^4
Expand[poly]
```

> 1 - 2 x^2 + 4 a^2 x^2 + x^4

```
ResourceFunction["CompleteSquare"][Expand@poly, x]
```

> 4 a^2 x^2 + (-1 + x^2)^2

Comment: Thanks!  This answer comes out of left field for me.  Can you explain more?  I looked up "ResourceFunction" and it seems it "finds" a user function (?) that happens to know how to "complete a square" in this context.  Is that right?  If so, where/what is this function?

Comment: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CompleteSquare/ . I learned about it from this forum. Can't say I know much about its internals.